# What tool can be used to to store ssh keys and how does it have to be configured?

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I want use a keyring app that stores my passphrases for my ssh keys. Moreover I should be asked once when I connect to the session and then it is stored.

At the moment I use `ssh-agent` and `keyring` in my `.zshrc`

```
# ssh-agent
if ! pgrep -u "$USER" ssh-agent > /dev/null; then
    ssh-agent -t 1h > "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/ssh-agent.env"
fi
if [[ ! "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]]; then
    source "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/ssh-agent.env" >/dev/null
fi

eval `keychain --eval --quiet --agents ssh superGoodKey`
eval $(keychain --eval --quiet ~/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

after every reboot when I open my terminal I need to enter the passphrases then it is saved for the session.

But prefer when I want to login with an ssh key to be asked once and then saved. Instead of being ask when I just open the terminal. Similar to the gnome-keyring without the graphical gui.

Answer (score 0):

Install the `pam_ssh` PAM module. The idea is similar, but it handles *just* the SSH agent – there is no intermediate keyring and it doesn't have any generic password storage features. Instead your login password will directly be used as the SSH key passphrase, to load `~/.ssh/id_rsa` as well as whatever keys you put in `~/.ssh/session-keys.d/*`.

The pam_ssh module will automatically maintain a single instance of ssh-agent across all sessions.

*(Note that installing pam_ssh on Debian will also have the side effect of activating pam_namespace, which gives each user a unique instance of /tmp – this might cause some confusion.)*

---

However, it should still be possible to use GNOME Keyring without a graphical UI – the `pam_gnome_keyring` module isn't limited to being used by GDM; it can be activated for text-based logins as well. (Though it needs to be called with slightly different options, to initialize the keyring-daemon immediately instead of waiting for GNOME to do it later.)